# R: Read text file in which new lines start after the nth observation

Tags: r

Here is an extract of my text file:

```
Assets
Notes
2017
2016
Cash
6
12,000,000
11,000,000
```

I would like to read this file into a data frame containing 4 columns. It should look something like this:

```
Assets   Notes   2017     2016
Cash      6      12000000 11000000
```

I'm thinking of looping to read a new line every four observations, but it looks like it's not the most efficient way to read the file into R. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's in a very regular order, convert to a matrix and then convert to a data frame.

Answer (score 3):

**1) base** Read `Lines` into character vector `L`.  At the bottom in the Note we show `Lines` reproducibly but you could replace the line that reads it in with the commented out line changing the file name appropriately.

Next remove commas and reshape it into an n x 4 matrix `m`.  Then collapse the rows into a string vector `L2` and read that with `read.table`.

No packages are used.

```
# L <- readLines("myfile")
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
m <- matrix(gsub(",", "", L),, 4, byrow = TRUE)
L2 <- apply(m, 1, paste, collapse = " ")
read.table(text = L2, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  Assets Notes     2017     2016
1   Cash     6 12000000 11000000
```

**2) dplyr/tidyr**  Using `L` from (1) we create a two column data frame with column name (using recycling) and contents and then spread it out to wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

L %>%
  { data.frame(Name = factor(.[1:4], levels = .[1:4]),
             Contents = gsub(",", "", .[-(1:4)])) } %>%
  spread(Name, Contents, convert = TRUE)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Assets
Notes
2017
2016
Cash
6
12,000,000
11,000,000"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- structure(list(V1 = c("Assets", "Notes", "2017", "2016", "Cash", 
                            "6", "12,000,000", "11,000,000")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))

data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), ncol = 4, byrow = T))
```